# How to correct code? Trying to output using list comprehension with lambda if/else statement using pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement, pointers, lambda, list-comprehension

would like to know why is my output for the following code pointers and not the values 1 or 0. How can it be corrected (using 1 line of list comprehension)?

Code:

```
winner_A = new['Winner']==new['A']
new['Winner_integer'] = [(lambda x: 1 if winner_A[row] is True else 0) for row in range(len(winner_A))]
```

Current output:

```
array([<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB48B8828>,
   <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB48B8798>,
   <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB48B8678>, ...,
   <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB57D7708>,
   <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB57D7798>,
   <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0000018DB57D7828>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your output is so weird is that

```
(lambda x: 1 if winner_A[row] is True else 0) for row in range(len(winner_A))
```

(the content of your list comprehension) is actually a *generator comprehension*,
generating just *lambda* functions, **without calling them**.

Another flaw in your code relates to `if winner_A[row] is True`.
In Python the *is* keyword is used to test if two variables refer to
**the same object**.
But in this fragment of your code:

- *winner_A[row]* is one *bool* expression (for some values of *row*
  it may be *True*),
- *True* (a *bool* literal) is **another** object.

So `if winner_A[row] is True` is **always** *False*.

Much simpler construct to generate what you want is:

```
new['Winner_integer'] = [ 1 if x else 0 for x in winner_A ]
```

returning a plain *pythonic* **list**, for my sample data `[1, 0, 0, 1]`,
which then is "packed" into consecutive elements of the new column.

Yet simpler costruct is just to convert *winner_A* (a *Series* of
*bool* type) to a *Series* of *int* type:

```
new['Winner_integer'] = winner_A.astype(int)
```

returning (also for my sample data):

```
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
dtype: int32
```

(check running this code without the left hand side).

The left column is the index and the right column - actual (*int*) values.
Then this *Series* is added to *new* DataFrame as a new column.

Answer (score 1):

since data frame was not provided I assume your data frame *has columns* like this...

`new = pd.DataFrame({'win_A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'A': [2, 2, 3, 3]})`
**Output: (new)**

```
   win_A  A
0      1  2
1      2  2
2      3  3
3      4  3
```

you are making new Series like this..

```
winner_A = new['win_A'] == new['A']
print(type(winner_A))
print(winner_A)
```

**output:**

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**in order to make your win_int column do this...**

```
new['win_int'] = winner_A.agg(lambda r: 1 if r else 0)
print(new)
```

**Output: (new)**

```
win_A   A   win_int
0   1   2   0
1   2   2   1
2   3   3   1
3   4   3   0
```

I think this is what you want !

**You can even do this without using winner_Integer variable like this...**
`new['win_int'] = (new['win_A'] == new['A']).agg(lambda r: 0 if r else 1)`

Comment: we usually don't use for loops while using pandas as they are slow... **I don't exactly know what is wrong with your for loop but** I can tell you that pandas columns are of type series and not array...